# Will I miss anything if I deactivate the in-game HUD display in Resident Evil 6?

Tags: resident-evil-6

There is an option to deactivate in-game HUD displays in Resident Evil 6. Would I miss secret areas or bonuses if I deactivate that? I prefer looking for objectives rather than it pointing out where to look, but I also don't want to miss anything important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised that once you turn it off, icons that show ammo, skills, and items on the floor will also disappear. Along with that, objective markers disappear such as waypoints to doors, keys and whereabouts of guns to be picked up.

However I did realise that herbs always show as a blue marker whether it's on or off. I checked this during a Boss fight so I am not sure if it's limited to that even only. Maybe someone can confirm this for me.